# Consistent linear system

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Prove that a consistent linear system $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions if and only if $Ax = 0$ has a nontrivial solution.

In order to prove this, we have to prove two separate statements, namely:

1) If $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions, $Ax = 0$ has a nontrivial solution.
2) If $Ax = 0$ has a nontrivial solution, $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions.

**Proof of statement 1:**
Since $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions, there are at least two distinct solutions, say $y_1$ and $y_2$, where $y_1 ≠ y_2$.

So $Ay_1 = b$ and $Ay_2 = b.$

Then, $A(y_1 – y_2) = Ay_1 – Ay_2 = b – b = 0.$
So $y_1 – y_2 ≠ 0$ is a nontrivial solution to $Ax = 0.$

**Proof of statement 2:**
If $Ax = 0$ has a nontrivial solution $y$, then $Ay = 0$, where $y≠0$.
If $Ax = b$, then
$A(y+x) = Ay + Ax = 0 + b = b$
According to the uniqueness theorem, $A(αy) = 0$ for any scalar $α$ if $A(y) = 0.$
Therefore, $A(αy + x) = A(αy) + Ax = 0 + Ax = b$ for any scalar $α$
So if $Ax = 0$ has a nontrivial solution, $Ax = b$ has infinitely many solutions.

Proof by contradiction:
If $Ax = 0$ has a trivial solution $y$, then $Ay = 0.$
Also, if $Ax = b$, then $A(y + x) = Ay + Ax = 0 + b = b.$
According to the uniqueness theorem, $A(αy) = 0$ for any scalar $α$ if $A(y) = 0.$
However, if $y = 0$, then $αy = 0$ for any scalar $α$, which implies that there is only one solution, not infinitely many.

---

Could someone verify my proof and see if I have worded anything incorrectly or missed anything?

Comment: You shouldn't have changed the question; you may *add* the new attempt.

Comment: Oh alright, noted. Thought it wouldn't really matter but I see now. Is the new attempt correct?

Answer (score 2):

Statement 1 is OK.

For the second you're not actually proving the statement, but you're on the right way.

The system $Ax=b$ is consistent. Let $y_0$ be a solution. Then prove that $y_0+\alpha y$ is a solution too, for $y\ne0$ and $Ay=0$.

Comment: I see what you mean, but isn't saying "$y_0 +αy$ is a solution too" the same as saying "A(αy) =0 for any scalar α if y is not equal to 0"? Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Stallmp In your attempt at statement 2 you never mention the system $Ax=b$, which is the system you have to prove it has infinitely many solution.

Comment: I have edited my proof for the second statement, is it correct now?